# how to Fill Image fullscreen in stackLayout in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

***how to Fill Image fullscreen in stackLayout  in Xamarin ?**
I can't set Image in fit to stacklayout
**.XAML File Code**

```
  <StackLayout Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <Image Source="ic_splash.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" > </Image>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Screenshot of Output Android and Window Phone....**
[image]  [image]
**I want to fit Image in Background.***

Comment: @chsword What do you mean by physical key ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Xamarin forms, I am using WebView.

Comment: Just remove the StackLayout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I solved problem using below code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="Your.Namespace.Views.LoginView"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             BackgroundImage="BackgroundImage.png">
  <StackLayout>
    <!-- Your stuff goes here -->
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**I have set background Image as fit to screen using above code....**

**`BackgroundImage="BackgroundImage.png"`**

Comment: Hi, I want to add 'scaleTo' property to the background image of the screen, If we use backgroundimage for fit the image in full screen we are not able apply 'scaleTo' property.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the *BackgroundImage* property is that the image proportion could change on screen size changed.

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-full-size-none-stretched) I found how to fill all the screen and save proportions using *RelativeLayout*:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Image Source="Jupiter.png" Opacity="0.3"
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
                "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
                "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
  <Grid RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint=
            "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint=
            "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">

    <Label Text="Hello world from XAML"/>
  </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with your first code you could set the image property aspect to AspectFill this would eventually crop your image though while maintaining the aspect ratio.

```
<StackLayout Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
<Image Source="ic_splash.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" > </Image>
```

Answer (score 2):

because there is no physical key on your android emulator.
by using a emulator with physical key will be well